# Passing Meteor's Iron Router Parameters to Template Callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

How do you pass the Iron Router parameters to a `Template.myTemplate.rendered` callback? The following route and callback function gives `undefined` for both `console.log`.

**URL**

```
http://localhost:3000/story/1234
```

**Router.js**

```
Router.map( function() {

    this.route('story', {
        path: '/story/:_id',
        template: 'story'
    })

})
```

**story.js**

```
Template.story.rendered = function () {

    console.log('params: ', this.params)    // undefined
    console.log('_id: ', this._id)    // undefined

}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Have you tried Router.current().params?

Comment: Np. Glad I could help. ;)

Comment: Will this work when we convert our code to mobile app?

Comment: I would assume so, but I've not created any mobile apps yet with Meteor to validate this.

Comment: awesome! was looking for this. @nickytonline when a beginner would need something like this, how would you search for it? I couldn't find it on my own, so I googled and finally found this solution.

Comment: Stackoverflow is a great resource for stuff like this. In the case of your issue, you probably have looked on the iron-router Github project page as well for documentation in regards to the aPI, https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router . Glad I coudl help you out.